# MongoDb 3.6 Compass connection with Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am building a java rest api    back end spring application and I need to connect it with mongo db compass edition- cloud-cluster. That means that I need to use this uri, in order to connect to the database.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<ClUSTER-NAME>-<INSTANCE-ID>/<DATABASE-NAME>?retryWrites=true
```

I have tried to follow this tutorial: `https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-mongodb-configuration` but I got an error, saying that this method SimpleMongoDbFactory is depricated. Unfortunately, I could not find an another tutorial so that I could finish my project. Also is it necessary to use spring boot ?

It is the first time that I am trying this connection and I do not know what else to do.
Any help appreciated !